# How can I use getElementByClassName instead of getElementById in order to duplicate an element?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

Good Afternoon,

I'm having trouble using 2 svg counters on my page.
I understand that I can use an Id only once per page but when I try to use getElementByClassName instead of getElementById nothing works.
How can I Duplicate my counter without using getElementByClassName or make the code work with it?

Here is the part of my javascript:

```
var canvasSize = 200,
centre = canvasSize/2,
radius = canvasSize*0.8/2,
s = Snap('#svg'),
path = "",
arc = s.path(path),    
startY = centre-radius,
runBtn = document.getElementById('run'),
percDiv = document.getElementById('percent'),
input = document.getElementById('input');

input.onkeyup = function(evt) {
if(isNaN(input.value)) {
  input.value = '';
}
};

runBtn.onclick = function() {
run(input.value/100);
};

function run(percent) {
var endpoint = percent*360;
Snap.animate(0, endpoint,   function (val) {
    arc.remove();

    var d = val,
        dr = d-90;
        radians = Math.PI*(dr)/180,
        endx = centre - radius*Math.cos(radians),
        endy = centre + radius * Math.sin(radians),
        largeArc = d>180 ? 1 : 0;  
        path = "M"+centre+","+startY+" A"+radius+","+radius+" 0 "+largeArc+",0 "+endx+","+endy;

    arc = s.path(path);
    arc.attr({
      stroke: '#3da08d',
      fill: 'none',
      strokeWidth: 12
    });
    percDiv.innerHTML =    Math.round(val/360*100) +'%';

}, 2000, mina.easeinout);  
}

run(input.value/100);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyyNxO

Comment: *"but when I try to use getElementByClassName instead of getElementById nothing works"* The method `getElementByClassName` doesn't exist. I assume you mean `getElement` **s** `ByClassName`. The documentation should provide enough information for you to learn how to use it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName .

Comment: show us the code for how you used getElementsByClassName and go from there. You may have to do everything twice, or just jQuery which can work on arrays of elements.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling), you want `getElementsByClassName` (plural element**s**), which will return an array-ish NodeList that you can use array methods on with `[].method.call()` and `[].method.apply()`.

So, I would save the input values in an object by `id` (maybe "btn1" and "btn2") and change the onclick assignment lines to something like:

```
var runBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
[].forEach.call(runBtns, function (btn) {
  btn.onclick = function () {
    run(input.value[btn.id] / 100);
  };
});
```